# How to know the predefined parameter in php functions?

Tags: php, function

If there is 2 parameter in php function how to know which parameter is kept in first and another second.

This is a php function `array_search($needle,$array)`. This will search `$needle` in an array `$array`.

In `array_slice($array, 2)` slice is to be done in an array `$array` is first parameter.

In `trim($string, 'abc')` trim is to be done in string $string is a first parameter.

Is there any way to remember which parameter come first? I think we can remember function but remembering parameter also is not possible for all functions.

Thanks

Comment: By frequent use and looking a lot into docs 
And if you use a IDE with autocomplete. it will be easy
Like PHPStorm , NetBeans

Comment: This has nothing to do with functional-programming...

Comment: Refer to documentation of function, if not clear how to invoke the function

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to PHP ,

> The likely most common complaint you get to hear about PHP is the
>   inconsistent and unclear naming of functions in the standard library,
>   as well as the equally inconsistent and unclear order of parameters.
>   Some typical examples:
>
> ```
> // different naming conventions
> strpos
> str_replace
>
> // totally unclear names
> strcspn                  // STRing Complement SPaN
> strpbrk                  // STRing Pointer BReaK
>
> // inverted parameter order
> strpos($haystack, $needle)
> array_search($needle, $haystack)
> ```

so if you want to check (*within your application and away from man pages*)

as a work around to get around this, you may make use of [`Reflection`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) collection in php :

for example:

```
function getFunctionInfo($functionName) {
    $function = new ReflectionFunction($functionName);

    return [
        'name' => $function->getName(),
        'parameters' => array_column($function->getParameters(), 'name'),
        'numberOfParameters' => $function->getNumberOfParameters(),
        'requiredParameters' => $function->getNumberOfRequiredParameters()
    ];
}

print_r(getFunctionInfo('explode'));
```

this will output:

```
Array ( 
    [name] => explode 
    [parameters] => Array ( 
        [0] => separator 
        [1] => str 
        [2] => limit 
    ) 
    [numberOfParameters] => 3 
    [requiredParameters] => 2 
)
```

and for live view: https://3v4l.org/T2Nad

the above quote had been quoted from : [nikic.github.io](http://nikic.github.io/2014/03/14/Methods-on-primitive-types-in-PHP.html)